# Flexbox children not having same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, tailwind-css

I thought flexbox makes its children having same height, meaning all children will be as tall as the highest (tallest) child and parent makes this by having default value of align-stretch for cross axis (if it is flex-row). In my case it is not like so.
I have following pen:
    [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwwwyG?editors=1010)

```
<div class="flex w-full items-center flex-wrap">
   <div class="flex flex-col md:w-1/2 items-center px-16 py-20 bg-red">
      <h2 class="marjan-col">Smaller text</h2>
      <p>This one has smaller text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="flex flex-col md:w-1/2 items-center px-16 py-20 bg-blue">
      <h2 class="text-white">Bigger text that controls element height</h2>
      <p class="text-white">
         Blue element has more text thus making red element smaller and unable to fit entire height 
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

- Note that taller element (background red) is not having same height as the blue element.
- I am using tailwind.css here, but I think code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `items-center` class from the *wrapper* class - this was adding `align-items: center` to your *flexbox* and overriding the *default stretch* behaviour - see demo below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css">

<div class="flex w-full flex-wrap">
  <!-- CHANGED HERE -->

  <div class="flex flex-col md:w-1/2 items-center px-16 py-20 bg-red">
    <h2 class="marjan-col">Smaller text</h2>
    <p>This one has smaller text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col md:w-1/2 items-center px-16 py-20 bg-blue">
    <h2 class="text-white">Bigger text that controls element height</h2>
    <p class="text-white">
      Blue element has more text thus making red element smaller and unable to fit entire height
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```